# Insert a javascript var into Highcharts data [ ]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, highcharts

I need some some help. I have a php file that make a count query into a database.

Then i have an index.html file witch use Highcharts script to make graph. I make an ajax call to return the count of my query like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'my.php',
   success: function (response) {
    var pro=response;
   }
});
```

Now, i have to insert the var pro into the Highcharts data[..., ..., ... ] to plot my graph.

I don't know how i can insert this var into data[..., ..., ...,].

Someone have some idea?

Thanks a lot to all!!

Comment: Are you creating a new chart, or modifying the data of an existing one?

Comment: I have only to add my var into a pseudo array like this:

 series: [{ name: 'Test',
                data: ['pro', 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]}

But this does not work, i need an alternatives

Comment: Why can't you just create the entire data array in the success function?

Comment: Because i have default data into this array and dynamic..

Comment: You need to post more of your javascript so we can see what other variables and processing you have.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the structure of `pro`. Provided it's a point struct, you could try this:

```
var chart = $('.chart').highcharts();
chart.series[0].addPoint([pro.x, pro.y]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have only to insert my var into data array like the up comment. I dont know how

Answer (score 0):

I advice to familiar with article about preprocessing data: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing

In case when you load php file, you need to pring array with numbers, not string or JSON.